# Can someone explain why the multinomial naive bayes classifier is linear?

Tags: classification, multinomial-distribution, linear, naive-bayes

I don't see how it is possible to write this as a linear function, yet it is said that it is. Can someone please explain how this is possible?

Comment: can you write down the formula for the classifier? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Multinomial_naive_Bayes

Comment: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e53303c0644c3d64e5eb86210023e76198285e0c

Comment: are you confused about properties of the logarithm, or are you confused as to why that conditional probability looks the way it does?

Comment: I'm confused as to why the conditional looks like this

Comment: Do you see where the multinomial distribution is inside the classifier?  If you take the log of a multinomial distribution, it's linear in the $x_i$.  The formula for the classifier itself is a straightforward application of Bayes' Rule.